Why does not exception handled by parent coroutine exception handler?
I test coroutineExceptionHandler.
Here is my code.
    fun createExceptionHandler(name: String) = CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, throwable ->
        println("[${Thread.currentThread().name} - $name] Caught $throwable\n${context[CoroutineExceptionHandler]}")
    }

    @Test
    fun coroutineScope_exceptionHandle() = runBlocking<Unit> {
        val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Job() + createExceptionHandler("supervisor"))
        coroutineScope.launch(createExceptionHandler("launch1")) {
            launch(CoroutineName("launch2") + createExceptionHandler("launch2")) {
                throw Exception("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Error !")
            }
            launch(CoroutineName("launch3")) {
                println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] launch3")
            }
        }
        delay(1000L)
    }

Result:
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 @launch3#6] launch3
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @launch2#5 - launch1] Caught java.lang.Exception: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @launch2#5] Error !
...

I expect the exception handled by coroutineScope's handler named supervisor.
Could you please explain why the exception handled by launch1 handler?

First - CoroutineExceptionHandler is only intended as a final consumer of uncaught exceptions. Installing it on child coroutines is not intended.
Second - Exception propagation in coroutines comes into play here. When a coroutine fails (throws) it fails its parent as well by forwarding exception to it. In that sense exception is not considered uncaught so exception handler of child has no need to "handle" it.
Only when there's no parent to forward exception to (root coroutine) the exception is considered uncaught and given to its exception handler.
In your particular case launch1 is root coroutine (launched directly in a scope) and its exception handler is being used to handle uncaught exception of its child - launch2. Failure of launch1 does cause the scope to get cancelled but exception that did it was already handled so its not forwarded to "supervisor" handler.

The way the launch function’s CoroutineContext parameter works is that it replaces all the parts of the parent scope’s context with the parts defined in the context parameter that you pass.
When you called launch you passed it a context consisting of a new exception handler ("launch1"). So the scope that the launched coroutine runs in is a child coroutine scope that uses the same context as the parent scope except for the exception handler, which is replaced with the newly defined one.
